# intermittent internet/DNS issues on Debian 9 fresh install

Tags: linux, networking, debian-stretch

I've just set up a Debian 9 home server and I'm having weird DNS issues. I've googled around but no luck so far. I'm not a Unix newbie but I know almost nothing about networking on linux. All I know about the issue is every so often all my internet based commands return something along the lines of  "Could not resolve host" some mention it being a temporary issue. Local networking is fine, although to start with I could connect using .local but now I have to use the IP address. The issue is only appearing on the Debian machine, other machines are working fine.

Sorry for not having much to go on, I have no clue where to start with this one.

[EDIT]
running `dig google.com` gives this:

```
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 14883
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.                    IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             75      IN      A       172.217.23.14

;; Query time: 16 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.254#53(192.168.1.254)
;; WHEN: Tue Sep 26 01:53:18 BST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55
```

and running `dig google.com @8.8.8.8` gives this:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> google.com @8.8.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I re-ran both of these while the issues were happening and both commands gave the second result

I think I've also added 8.8.8.8 as a nameserver, `nmcli` gives this:

```
DNS configuration:
    servers: 192.168.1.254 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: If it's a DNS issue try changing the DNS server to the correct one or use Google's 8.8.8.8 .

Comment: Try using the `nslookup`, or better yet, `dig`  commands to see if you can resolve the IP address in that way. Ideally you would check against the default resolver for the system like `dig google.com` and against a specific public DNS server like `dig google.com @8.8.8.8` Reporting the results back here will aid in answering your question.

Comment: Updated question with more info

Comment: You have both a local nameserver, probably from your router, and Google's nameserver (check `/etc/resolv.conf` to verify). One of those will be picked at random for each DNS lookup, and of one has trouble (could be either one, e.g. when Google NS access is filtered somewhere), every so often you'll have those failures. So (1) configure just *one* nameservers for (2) each of those in turn, and (3) see which is problematic, then (4) use the other one.

Comment: I've done that, seems that I need to use 8.8.8.8. However now the nameserver in `resolv.conf` keeps getting reset to the bad one, how do I prevent this?